# How to build a chart based on values of textfield inputs?

Tags: jquery, charts

I have a page with 10 textfields that are filled dynamically depending on what the use has input on a previous page.

I want to display these values in a simple bar chart.  I have setup jqPlot, yes I cannot seem to get it to work.  Is it possible someone could take a look at the 2nd page here and let me know how to call textfield input values to build a bar chart?

http://www.beatinganger.com/stress-test

It would be much appreciated.

Comment: jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js does not exist. You may want to start by fixing that.

Comment: Thanks, that makes the example work, now I just cant seem to call the valuyes of the textfields..

Comment: Cool , no worries I have ticked the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var ticks = [], vals = [];
    $('#edit-submitted-physical-state, #edit-submitted-mental-state, #edit-submitted-feelingso-of-belonging, #edit-submitted-feelings-of-justice, #edit-submitted-feeings-of-integrity, #edit-submitted-weight-management, #edit-submitted-emotional-ease, #edit-submitted-feelings-of-stimulation, #edit-submitted-feelings-of-justice, #edit-submitted-feelings-of-relationsip')
        .each(function(i, el) {
            vals.push(Number(el.value));
            ticks.push($('label[for="'+el.id+'"]').text().replace('Feelings of ', '').replace(': ', ''));
        });

    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [vals], {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I'm looping through all of the fields and pushing the value of each into the `vals` array. Remember, jQuery's `.val()` returns only the value of the first matched item. I'm also using `Number()` to make sure they are numbers and not strings.

You'll probably want to do something else with `ticks` - I'm just putting numbers in.

I'd recommend that you set a special class on all the text fields you want to read, and then reference them all with that class, instead of using the IDs. Then line 3 above would read simply:

```
$('.special_class_here').each(function(i, el) {
```

Comment: You sir, are an absolute genius. It is late, and my body and mind thank you kindly!!!  One question if you do have a moment though - how do I assign the appropriate labels on the horizontal axis to the values?  At the moment, there are just numbers.

Comment: Anyway even if you cant tell me, thankyou so much I can sleep easy!

Comment: What do you want the axis labels to say?

Comment: Physical, Mental, Emotional, Weight, Belonging, Justice, Stimulation etc etc as long as they correspond to the appropriate value - just so the user can see what it is. thanks again mark

Comment: I edited my answer to put the labels in; however, the chart appears to be too small for them to fit. I think you can figure it out from here.

Comment: I think the solution is to make the bars horizontal by adding `rendererOptions: { barDirection: 'horizontal' }` to the seriesDefaults section. See http://www.jqplot.com/tests/barRendererTests.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just pass the ids of the anwsers and not the value. You need to pass

```
$("edit-submitted-mental-state").val()
```

Comment: Thanx macarthy - I have tried this, yet it isnt coming up with a graph. Im at a total loss! thanks anyway.

Comment: Hahaha, im so over it now, just want to find a solution though :)